# Shape issue when running fit with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to run an autoencoder with keras, but im getting a shape error that I have tried to solve for a while but still keep getting the same error.

```
   df['Amount'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df['Amount'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
   df0 = df.query('Class==0').sample(20000)
   df1 = df.query('Class==1').sample(400)
   df = pd.concat([df0, df1])

   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(labels=['Time', 'Class'], axis=1),
                                                      df['Class'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
 
   encoding_dim = 12
   input_dim = x_train.shape[1]

   inputArray = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
   encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(inputArray)

   decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation='softmax')(encoded)

   autoencoder = Model(inputArray, decoded)
   autoencoder.summary()

   autoencoder.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),
                   loss='mean_squared_error',
                   metrics=['mae', 'accuracy'])
```

After I run the above, I try the following and then I get the error: "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (29,) but got array with shape (1,)"

````
epochs = 20

history = autoencoder.fit(x_train, y_train,
                         batch_size = batch_size,
                         epochs=epochs,
                         verbose=1,
                         shuffle=True,
                         validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
                         callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='../logs/autoencoder1')])```
````

Comment: the shapes are -> x_train: (16320, 29), x_test:(4080, 29), y_train:(16320,), y_test:(4080)

Comment: can you give us the result of autoencoder.summary()

Comment: When training an autoencoder, there is no y_train, you use x_train and input and targets, so you have a big conceptual misunderstanding, and that is why the error appears

Comment: here is the result of autoencoder.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   

input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 29)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 12)                360       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 29)                377       
=================================================================
Total params: 737
Trainable params: 737
Non-trainable params: 0

Comment: about the using of y_train, i was following the instructions of a  book im using, and the code there was written this way, when I took y_train off, i got a "out of range index" error

Answer (score 0):

The error states that there is a mismatch between the model output shape and the data that you are passing as target. Check the shape of y_train. Also, in the fit call `validation_data=(x_test, x_test)` is a mistake. It should be `(x_test, y_test)`.

If you intent the output of the model to be a category you can try using a sparse_categorical loss which then expects a y_train shape of (1,).

An mse loss expects the model output shape to match y_train.

Comment: I tried with y_test at first and i got the same error, but i'll try and see if using sparse_categorical loss will solve, thank you.

Comment: like, the shape of y_train is (16320,), so it matches the number of lines in x_train, but i dont know why is giving me an error. Should it be (29,)? if yes, then there is error on the data i got? because i got it from kaggle, so it kind of confuses me..

Comment: with the sparse_categorical it worked, thank you so much for the help

Comment: @viniciuscatelaniCatelani would you mind accepting the answer or are there additional details you would like to see clarified ?

Comment: It's fine,i got what i needed with the answer,thank you for helping